# Is there 'switch user' add-on available for Node.js that behaves similar to the Grails plugin

Tags: node.js, spring-security, jwt, grails-plugin

I have a Grails application where we use the [Grails Spring Security plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/switchUser.html) to allow an admin to easily switch (or assume) another user. This has proven to be very useful for admins to debug user issues and for our testers to jump between roles.

Is there an easy solution available for Node.js that is similar to this Spring Security feature? Note that we're using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) to auth every request, so not using server based token like Spring Security would.

Answer (score 1):

No, but only because there is no equivalent security plugin for Node in the first place. There are popular projects such as http://passportjs.org/ that can provide functionality in this category, and each offers varying levels of support for what you're asking. But your request isn't relevant to NodeJS Core. User authentication and authorization are not core modules of that project.

Comment: Being newer to Node than the Java ecosystem, which frameworks within Node are used extensively for auth? Do any of those frameworks have this type of functionality built in. I did some searching and never saw anything like this even though it seems like it would be a common feature to auth.

Comment: You should begin your investigation with Passport. It's the single most popular auth library out there and its plugin-based model allows all kinds of extensibility like this.